# Simulink: individual signal output from bus input (based on signal name)

Tags: matlab, struct, simulink, bus

I have a complex Simulink model and want to generate in a subsystem one simple error message signal out of a lot of incoming error observing signals. 
These incoming signals are organised in a bus and are always 0, exept when an error occurs: then there is an edge to *value*.
The error message should contain an individual bit code which is defined for every error name and error value in an excel list.

How can I assign this error code to a specific error signal with rising edge? I need something like a lookup function:

> **for** (every signal):
>
> **if** signal has edge to *value*,
>    look in list to signal name
>   and output its error code.

My idea was to use a MATLAB function block with a bus input and a one-dimensional output. A .mat file generated before Simulation start contains a struct with the list inputs from the excel file and should be used as a parameter in the MATLAB function.

This solution seems a bit difficult though, since dynamic field referencing and interating through a structure is not supported for code generation. I cannot even get the signal name from the struct because the *fieldnames* function is not supported, too.

I am now wondering if there is another approach or the MATLAB function is still doable for my problem. Can I generate the code for the MATLAB function block in a PreLoadfcn? Does a S-function make sense here? Or is there even a Simulink based solution which does the Signal conversion?